# Default kernel parameters on new network namespaces

Tags: sysctl, network-namespaces, kernel-parameters

What are the default kernel parameters, when creating a new network namespace? Is there a way to override them upon creation?

I think they are inherited by the parent process. An example using unshare:

```
> /sbin/sysctl -a --pattern 'net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding'
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
> unshare -n
> /sbin/sysctl -a --pattern 'net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding'
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
```

Comment: 1) I think your answer has good evidence. 2) This seems similar to how `fork()` just clones a process, then you have to apply any changes you want to make to the clone as normal.  Why wouldn't using `sysctl --load` satisfy your question?

Comment: @sourcejedi Yes I could use `sysctl --load`. I was wondering if there was a way to do it in one step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your surmise is correct, they are inherited from the parent namespace.  This seems similar to how processes clone themselves using the `fork()` system call, then any desired changes have to be applied *by the clone*, using the normal system calls.  (Including replacing the current program with a completely different one, using `exec()`.  `fork()`+`exec()` being how e.g. the shell runs other programs, although this magic is not usually visible to the user).

None of the options to the underlying `unshare` system call change this.  So I'd say the answer to your question is no.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html

---

Oh... that wasn't even an analogy!  Look at the option flags:

> `CLONE_NEWNET` (since Linux 2.6.24)
>
> This flag has the same effect as the `clone(2)` CLONE_NEWNET
>                 flag.  Unshare the network namespace, so that the calling
>                 process is moved into a new network namespace which is not
>                 shared with any previously existing process.  Use of
>                 CLONE_NEWNET requires the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability.

`clone()` basically means `fork()`.

> Since version 2.3.3, rather than invoking the kernel's fork() system
>          call, the glibc fork() wrapper that is provided as part of the NPTL
>          threading implementation invokes clone(2) with flags that provide the
>          same effect as the traditional system call.  (A call to fork() is
>          equivalent to a call to clone(2) specifying flags as just SIGCHLD.)